# Soft-keyboard squeezes textedit box in Android

Tags: java, android, manifest, android-softkeyboard

How can I solve the following issue? What I would like to happen is for the input window to be displaced, not squeezed, by the soft-keyboard.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had to add this line INSIDE the "activity" tags.

Comment: @Forset1 move it to your `<activity>` tag